# Which part takes more time, using function or using global?

Tags: php, performance, function, scope, global

Can you please tell me why second code runs two times faster than first code (6 sec and 11 sec) (in all php versions)? The reason is for using function or using global or anything else and why? I want to prevent this mistake in other script but I don't know what is exactly my mistake.

I run this script with online tools but have the same result.

profile first code:
[image]
First code:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 2500; ++$i) {
    $pen[$i] = $i * (3 * $i - 1 ) / 2;
}
function pentagonal($num) {
    global $pen;
    return $pen[$num];
}
function is_pentagonal($c) {
    $x = (1+sqrt(1+24*$c))/(6);
    if ($x == (int)$x) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
for ($i = 2;  ; ++$i) {
    for ($j = 1; $j < $i ; ++$j) {
        $pi = pentagonal($i); // Here is the difference
        $pj = pentagonal($j); // Here is the difference
        if (is_pentagonal($pi + $pj, $pen)) {
            if (is_pentagonal(abs($pi - $pj), $pen)) {
                $difference = $pi - $pj;
                break 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
echo $i.' '.$j.' '.$difference."\n";
```

Second code (just removing function and get the value directly from array):

```
    for ($i = 1; $i < 2500; ++$i) {
        $pen[$i] = $i * (3 * $i - 1 ) / 2;
    }
//    function pentagonal($num) {
//        global $pen;
//        return $pen[$num];
//    }
    function is_pentagonal($c) {
        $x = (1+sqrt(1+24*$c))/(6);
        if ($x == (int)$x) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    for ($i = 2;  ; ++$i) {
        for ($j = 1; $j < $i ; ++$j) {
            $pi = $pen[$i];  // Here is the difference
            $pj = $pen[$j];  // Here is the difference
            if (is_pentagonal($pi + $pj, $pen)) {
                if (is_pentagonal(abs($pi - $pj), $pen)) {
                    $difference = $pi - $pj;
                    break 2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo $i.' '.$j.' '.$difference."\n";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lookup of a variable, global or otherwise, in dynamic languages is usually implemented as an table lookup (either a hash lookup or an offset). This is very fast. A function call is always "expensive"... there is a certain amount of setup and teardown code that needs to be executed, and this can translate to many thousands of machine code instructions. This is, in comparison, slow.

Be that as it may, it would be foolish to replace all the function calls by direct variable access in a bigger system. If your problem is entirely expressed in the code above, then yes, access the variables directly, AND THROW AWAY THE CODE WHEN YOU HAVE FINISHED.

If this is part of a larger system, use functions. It makes testing, debugging, static analysis, profiling, everything,... much, much easier. Even if the first variant of the code is twice as fast as the second, it will pretty much be lost in the noise of everything else that's going on, especially once any IO occurs.

UPDATE: You might make your function a bit more efficient by expressing it as...

```
function is_pentagonal($c) {
    $x = (1+sqrt(1+24*$c))/(6);
    return $x == (int)$x;

}
```

... as this will avoid creating lexical scopes (or whatever they're called in PHP).